# What is the Maximal Solution of the below Cauchy problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

Let us define this Cauchy Problem:

$$\frac{d x(t)}{dt}=(1+t^2)(\exp(x(t)-1)) \cos(x^2(t)), \quad x(0)=1, (t,x)\in \mathbb{R^2}$$

I have tried to show that ODE have a unique maximal Solution $\phi$ over $I=]T_{1},T_{2}[$ of class $C^1$ using the Cauchy-Lipchitz theorem but I didn't succeed.

And what is the limit of this solution for $t \to \pm\infty$?

Comment: The equation has the form $\dot x=f(x)g(t)$. What are the roots of $f$? What roots $a,b$ enclose $x(0)$? Show that these roots also enclose any $x(t)$. What sign does the derivative $\dot x$ take on this interval?

Comment: Ok, is there any way to get the explicite form of that maximal solution ?

Comment: No. You can integrate after separation of variables, but the integral for $x$ is not symbolically representible, so even thinking about inverting it is futile.